# На какое именно из ранее упомянутых существительных указывает указательное местоимение "та"?

Tags: местоимения

**Он обратился гримом и начал ластиться к Виктории Колычевой, которая отпугивала судью-псину палочкой, но та упала на пол.**

---

Известно, что местоимение тот/та указывает на отдалённый предмет или упоминавшийся ранее. На какой именно предмет (Виктория Колычева или же палочка) указывает "та" в данном предложении? Возник небольшой конфликт по причине того, что одни воспринимают "та" в связке с Викторией, а другие относят местоимение к палочке. Оба предмета указывались ранее.

Comment: *Обратился гримом* — здесь ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

То, что обозначенное ранее в предложении обозначает местоимение, определяется двумя способами — род и по смыслу. Если есть предложение: ‟Я увидел человека в шляпе, которая странно выглядела”, то мы поймём, что слово ‟которая” обозначает то же самое, что и ‟шляпа”, по женскому роду; если есть предложение: ‟Я видел человека в шляпе, который странно выглядел”, то мы поймем, что ‟который” относится к слову ‟мужчина”, по мужскому роду. Теперь представим такое предложение: ‟Я увидел человека на мотоцикле, который смотрел вдаль”. У слов ‟человек” и ‟мотоцикл” одинаковый род, но мы понимаем, что ‟который” относится к ‟человек” потому, что мотоцикл не может смотреть вдаль (могут быть какие-то фигуральные приёмы, но это не тот случай). То есть есть два способа определить: либо род, либо подходящее по смыслу. По роду здесь нельзя определить, потому что там всё женского рода, а чтобы определить по смыслу, то желательно знать контекст и все тонкие особенности его — кто эти люди, где они находятся, что они делают и т.д. Я вообще не понимаю, что значит ‟обратился гримом”, кто обратился гримом, где обратился гримом, что значит здесь слово ‟ластится”, кто такая Виктория, какая судья-псина, какой ещё палочкой кто отгоняет какую-то судью-псину. Все это без контекста звучит как наркоманский бред шизофреника, поэтому нельзя ответить на этот вопрос, не понимая контекста. Конечно же люди не понимают, что к чему там относится!

Comment: Согласна, сама боялась, что из-за контекста (а именно из-за его отсутствия) может быть неясна суть, но изменять не стала во избежание ещё большего непонимания) Если дело в роде, то суть ясна, благодарю за мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "та" немного хочется отнести к человеку, потому что обычно им на людей ссылаются. Если не вчитываться, то можно подумать, что судья упала (вот у меня так вышло). Лучше заменить на "она":
*Он обратился гримом и начал ластиться к Виктории Колычевой, которая отпугивала судью-псину палочкой, но **она** упала на пол.*

Дополнительная информация:
Если по смыслу два существительных равносильны (например, два человека), то относится к последнему (иначе неверно написано). Ещё "но" помогает понять, противопоставление с ним делается к тому, что было только что сказано.